# Harvesting energy from solar and "USB"

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I'm designing circuit based on a microcontroller, powered by a solar cell. As an experiment, I wanted to add an energy harvesting IC ([bq25504](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25504.pdf)). When programming, I'd like to be able to charge the battery through the USB port as well.

I thought of also feeding the current from this port to the input of the harvester.

But the problem is: I can't use a diode in series with the solar cell. The energy harvesting IC is so efficient it can harvest energy from voltages as low as 80mV, so if I add a series diode I'd be losing that ability.

What would happen if I put the V of the programming port in parallel with the solar cell? Will the solar cell get damaged because of reverse-biasing?

Comment: -5V is safe , -6 is not

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 is it the same for all panels? There are single-cell ones rated for 0.5V OC, can I put -3.3V across them?

Comment: show me the datasheet

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 well, it's a Shenzhen Special so there's not really much info. Guess I'll have to test them myself.